# Bootstrap 3 mobile navigation not showing correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am having unexpected and unusual challenges with a Bootstrap 3 navigation on this [site](http://camclinic.com/). It works properly in all views except mobile where the dropdown navigation shows up behind the page content - see screenshot.

[image]

I have compared my navigation code with the code samples on getbootstrap.com and can't see any problems:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default {if segment_1 == ""}hidden-xs{/if}" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
     <a class="navbar-brand phone-home" href="tel:910-342-0999">910-342-0999</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <div class="logo hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"><a href="/">Cameron Clinic</a></div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="/about/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About <span class="caret hidden-sm hidden-md"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="/about/">Nan Cameron</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about/#office-coordinator">Office Coordinator</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about/#office-policy">Office Policy</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about/#what-to-expect">What to Expect</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about/patient-forms">Patient Forms</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="/services/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Services <span class="caret hidden-sm hidden-md"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="/services/#clinical-evaluation">Clinical Evaluation</a></li>
                <li><a href="/services/#acupuncture">Acupuncture</a></li>
                <li><a href="/services/#botanical-nutritional-supplements">Botanical & Nutritional<br />  Supplements</a></li>
                <li><a href="/services/#biomat">Biomat</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/the-club-at-cam-clinic/">Club</a></li>
        <li><a href="/patient-testimonials/">Testimonials</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Info & Education <span class="caret hidden-sm hidden-md"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="/information-and-education/articles">Articles</a></li>
            <li><a href="/information-and-education/events-and-lectures">Events & Lectures</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Resources <span class="caret hidden-sm hidden-md"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="/resources/smiling-practice">Smiling Practice</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/resources/affiliated-clinic">Affiliated Clinic</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/resources/links">Links</a></li>
                    </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div><!-- /.navbar -->
```

I would really appreciate an extra set of eyes to help me find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you have used fixed height in your style.css file. I will suggest you to use min-height instead of height or height:auto;
[image: Preview]

```
@media (max-width: 1199px){ //style.css:1084
  .navbar-default {
      min-height: 40px; 
   }
.navbar-default {  //style.css:142
    min-height: 107px;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #C4B4D3;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
```

}

Comment: Bless you my dear friend. That solved the problem. My hair can now start to grow back. You were so kind to help out.